# How to add text in the middle of a chart in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Consider this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u57k1kL/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        marginLeft: 80
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Title aligned left',
        align: 'left',
        x: 70
    },
    series: [{
        //data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

I want to have a default text in the middle of the chart, if the data is empty.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3):

There is a specific module for that called `no-data-to-display.js` and you can customize the text too like that :

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang:{
        noData:'Something is missing !' // Your text when there is no data
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/8d8dn1pt/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `loading` option to show some text in middle of the chart when you have no data:

```
lang:{
    loading: 'your text here'
},
```

Then call `showLoading()` to show this text when you have no data. [Here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/loading) are the documentation of how to customize the loading text.

#### Working example:

```js
let my_chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        marginLeft: 80
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Title aligned left',
        align: 'left',
        x: 70
    },
    lang:{
     loading: 'your text here'
    },
    series: [{
        //data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});

if (!my_chart.series[0].data.length)
    my_chart.showLoading()
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```